# Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history

Tags: svn, git, macos, git-svn

I get this on every git svn command I try. I am using git version 1.6.4.2 on OS 10.6

The initial git svn fetch works, and i can do further fetches after that, but they do not enter the log or update the working copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git svn fetch` just downloads the revisions into your local repository.  You still need to either `git merge $remoteBranch` to get the changes into your current branch.  You can update your current branch in one step by running `git svn rebase`, but that only downloads the new commits for that remote branch.

The same would be true for a normal git repository.  Doing a simple `git fetch` doesn't pull the new commits into your current branch.  It simply downloads them and you need to `git merge` them into your branch.